# Textarea submitting ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use this, it works

```
<%= form_for(@patient, url: patient_add_comment_path(@patient)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :doctor_comment, cols: 65, rows: 3, style: "resize: none; border: 2px solid #888; background-color:#FFF; font-size: 16px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:5px;", placeholder: "doktor comment.." %>
    <%= f.text_area :hidden_comment, cols: 65, rows: 3, style: "resize: none; border: 2px solid #888; background-color:#FFF; font-size: 16px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:5px;", placeholder: "doktor hidden comment.." %>
    <%= f.submit "Kaydet", class: "btn btn-circle green-haze btn-sm", style: "margin-top: 5px;"%>
<% end %>
```

But I wanted to use text editor for this for using the class of 'summernote_1'

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <%= form_for(@patient, url: patient_add_comment_path(@patient)) do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Doktor Comment <%= f.text_area :doctor_comment, class: "summernote_1"%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Hidden Comment <%= f.text_area :hidden_comment, class: "summernote_1"%>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-circle green-haze btn-sm", style: "margin-top: 5px;"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Bu when I click Save button, the link try to send and it does not update, how can I solve this problem?

```
http://localhost:3000/doctors/2?utf8=✓&_method=patch&authenticity_token=OPPiCvNbcONDyHzzEQ%3D%3D&patient[doctor_comment]=asdfadsfasdfasdfasdfa&patient[hidden_comment]=asdfadsfasd&commit=Save
```

Comment: Could you please add the HTML generated by each example?

Comment: Is there some JS observed to the class "summernote_1"? Please also post the generated HTML.

Comment: How can I post the generated HTML?

Comment: Open your page in a brower, view its code. Copy and paste

Comment: I believe you're missing parentheses. Try:

 f.text_area(:doctor_comment, class: "summernote_1")